# Thrust issue with CUDA 6 managed memory

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am running into an issue where when trying to use cudaMallocManaged() and thrust in the same CUDA 6 application thrust fails, even when thrust is not using any of the managed memory. Simply having an unused managed variable is enough to cause thrust to fail. I have created the following reproducer which I am testing on an NVIDIA Jetson TK1 running CUDA 6.0:

```
#include "thrust/device_ptr.h"
#include "thrust/sort.h"

__global__ void calculate_hash(uint *hash_values, uint *particle_ids, int length)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(i >= length)
        return;

    hash_values[i] =  1;
    particle_ids[i] = i;
}

void hash_particles_gpu(uint *d_hash_values, uint *d_particle_ids, int length)
{
    int block_size = 256;
    int num_blocks = ceil(length/(float)block_size);

    calculate_hash<<<num_blocks, block_size>>>(d_hash_values, d_particle_ids, length);  

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    thrust::device_ptr<uint> keys(d_hash_values);
    thrust::device_ptr<uint> values(d_particle_ids);
    thrust::sort_by_key(keys, keys+length, values);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int length = 15;
    int bytes;

    #ifdef BROKE
    int *m_int;
    cudaMallocManaged((void**)&m_int, sizeof(int));
    #endif

    // Allocate uint hash value array
    bytes = length*sizeof(unsigned int);
    unsigned int * hash_values;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&hash_values, bytes);    

    // Allocate uint particle ID array
    bytes = length*sizeof(unsigned int);
    unsigned int *particle_ids;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&particle_ids, bytes);

    hash_particles_gpu(hash_values, particle_ids, length);
}
```

When I compile and run:

```
$ nvcc -DBROKE -DTHRUST_DEBUG example.cu -o broke.exe
$ nvcc -DTHRUST_DEBUG example.cu -o fixed.exe
$ ./fixed.exe
$ ./broke.exe
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  synchronize: RakingReduction: unknown error
Abort
```

I have checked to make sure I do not have any errors up until this point and everything seems fine until I call sort_by_key. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What happens if you do proper cuda error checking on the `cudaMallocManaged` call.  Are any API errors reported?  What operating system are you running on that Jetson platform?

Comment: I've checked all of the cuda functions and kernel launches and none return any error up until sort_by_key. the TK1 is running the default Linux For Tegra(L4T). Separately thrust and managed memory seem to functions correctly.

Comment: Perhaps you could try CUDA 6.5RC to see if the behavior is any different.  Other than that, I don't have any ideas but could suggest you file a bug with NVIDIA.

Comment: I have tried this code on a Kepler K20c, c.c. `3.5`, and I cannot reproduce the problem. Are you sure about your compilation command? Should you specify the compute capability?

Comment: All permuatations of this work fine for me on an x86_64 linux platform with CUDA 6.0 and an sm_30 device as well. This looks like some sort of ARM or L4T specific issue. I would raise a bug report with NVIDIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I flashed the latest Linux for Tegra, 19.3, and it works now with Cuda 6.0. Looks like NVIDIA had a driver issue with L4T 19.2.